# Set dynamic data to dynamically created table in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I am getting array of objects from database. Data may not be same for all time, it may be different.

My data is of the format,

```
var items = [
    { Name: "Apple" },
    { Name: "Orange"},
    { Name: "Banana"},
    { Name: "Cherry"},
    { Name: "ABC"}

];
```

I want to arrange these data in blocks or tiles or tables such that column block should be number of 3. That is I am expecting a result as,

```
 Apple      Orange    Banana
 Cherry     ABC
```

I have tried some code as,

```
    var html = "";
    html += '<tr>'
    html += '<td>';
    html +='<div class="row">';
    html +='<div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='<div class="col-md-4">';
    var k=1;
     $.each(items,function(key,val){
            if(k==2){
            html +='</div>';
            html +='<div class="col-md-4">';
        }
        if(k==3){
            html +='</div>';
            html +='<div class="col-md-4">';
        }

        html +=val.Name;
        k++;    


     });
     html +='</div></div></div>';
     html += '</td>';
     html += '</tr>';
    $('#maindiv').html(html);
```

I know this is wrong, main reason is I am new to this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try this: remove the `row` and `col-md-12` wrappers, then just put each one in a `col-md-4` - all together, don't try and break them yourself, the`-md-4` will do this for you

Comment: @freedomn-m then it will be in a single column

Comment: Given that you're using `col-md-4` I, perhaps incorrectly, *assumed* you were also using bootstrap.  Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q0vfm92b/ (make sure it's wide enough for `-md-` otherwise, yes, you get a single column) - does exactly what you're asking for (bootstrap 3)

Comment: all are adding dynamically, so I think I can add class of bootstrap

Comment: Can you show me a code sample. I followed as you said, but it's not working

Comment: @DimitarPashovski 's answer is essentially the same.  If you use `col-md-4` then you need a "medium" screen, so if it's a single column, could be your screen isn't wide enough - try using the browser zoom down to 10% to see what happens in your output

Comment: It's not working for me, Can you give me a clean sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method for much simpler solution

```
var row = $('<div class="row"></div>');

jQuery.each(items, function(index, value) {

    var column = $('<div class="col-md-4">'+value.Name+'</div>');
    row.append(column);

});

$('#maindiv').append(row);
```

Comment: I tried this,even though  no errors are showing I am not getting any view. It's empty, nothing is displayed there.

Comment: Check for typos - `class="row>` `class="col-md-4>`

Comment: yap that is the problem :) sorry... edited my answer